# How do you convert a varchar2 into a number with two decimal places?

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

Sorry, I am new at Oracle and am having some troubles selecting some numbers that are in a table that are `varchar2`.

I need them to be numbers with 2 decimal places.

for example:

```
00008600  
00202033  
00094123
```

need to be

```
86.00  
2020.33  
941.23
```

How would I be able to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
select to_char(to_number(yourcol)/100.0, '9999999d99') yourColFormatted
from yourTable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/9244)